# What does 具志川mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, words

Does it mean a sandy marshy area by a river? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a name of place, [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gushikawa,_Okinawa.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gushikawa,_Okinawa)

具志 is a famous okinawan name, it means "Back side shape of building/architecture" in okinawan.